# Return results of SQL query on one row

Tags: sql, select, double

```
SELECT
    Tickets.id,
    (SELECT Users.Name FROM Users INNER JOIN Tickets ON Tickets.Creator = Users.id) AS naam,
    (SELECT Users.Name FROM Users INNER JOIN Tickets ON Tickets.Owner = Users.id) AS name
FROM Tickets
WHERE Tickets.id = 64;
```

I want on one row

```
id, username(Tickets.creator= Users.id), username(where Tickets.Owner = Users.id)
```

`Users`

```
id | name
----------
1  | jan
2  | henk
3  | maria
```

`tickets`

```
ticketsid | owner     | creator
-------------------------------
1         | 3         | 2
2         | 1         | 3
3         | 2         | 3
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you really want. Can you post the result table you wish to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
select t.id, o.name, c.name
  from tickets t
  join users o on o.id = t.owner
  join users c on c.id = t.creator
 where t.id = 64;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your queries want to be correlated with the outer query.  You as missing that by doing an additional join to `tickets`:

```
SELECT
    Tickets.id,
    (SELECT Users.Name FROM Users WHERE Tickets.Creator = Users.id) AS naam,
    (SELECT Users.Name FROM Users WHERE Tickets.Owner = Users.id) AS name
FROM Tickets
WHERE Tickets.id = 64;
```

You can also express this query with `join`s:

```
select t.id, uc.name as CreatorName, uo.name as OwnerName
from Tickets t left outer join
     Users uc 
     on t.Creator = uc.id left outer join
     Users uo
     on t.Owner = uo.id
where t.id = 64;
```

This would be the more typical way of expressing this query.